# U-boot. BeagleBone Black. Micro SD card

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

I have a series of questions on how U-boot works on the BeagleBone Black. Everything started with this tutorial on how to use a micro SD card(uSD) as extra storage.

[uSD as extra storage on BBB.](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:MicroSD_As_Extra_Storage)

Currently my setup looks like this.

```
$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7948 MB, 7948206080 bytes #uSD
        Device Boot  Start      End  Blocks Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1        2048   198655   98304  e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      198656 15523839 7662592 83  Linux

Disk /dev/mmcbk1: 3867 MB, 3867148288 bytes #eMMC
        Device Boot Start     End  Blocks Id System
/dev/mmcblk1p1    *  2048  198655   98304  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk1p2     198656 7553023 3677184 83 Linux
```

So if I havent had it wrong this is what happends.

```
Boot sequence.
    1.The BBB is powered.
    2.The U-boot is loaded from the eMMC(/dev/mmcblk1p1)
    3.The U-boot searches for uEnv.txt file within the uSD(/dev/mmcblk0p1) and loads it.
    ...... We will retake from here.
```

In `/dev/mmcblk0p1` i have a `uEnv.txt` file that looks like this.

```
mmcdev=1
bootpart=1:2
mmcroot=/dev/mmcblk1p2 ro
optargs=quiet
```

In `/dev/mmcblk1p1` i have the default `uEnv.txt` file that at some point have this lines.

```
loadkernel=load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} ${kernel_file}
loadinitrd=load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${initrd_addr} ${initrd_file}; setenv initrd_size ${filesize}
.......
mmcargs=setenv bootargs console=tty0 console=${console} ${optargs} ${kms_force_mode} root=${mmcroot} rootfstype=${mmcrootfstype} ${systemd}
```

We can see how ${mmcdev}, ${mmcroot}, ${optargs} are used although they arent defined in the file, they are defined uSD uEnv.txt.

```
Question 1.
    ¿Does this mean that both uEnv.txt files are loaded?
```

Retaking the boot sequence.

```
Boot sequence.
    4.The U-boot searches for uEnv.txt file within the eMMC(/dev/mmcblk1p1) and loads it.
    5.The Linux kernel is loaded.
```

When there is no uSD the ${mmcdev}, ${mmcroot}, ${optargs}  arguments aren't defined, not in the uEnv.txt at least.

```
Question 2.   
    ¿Where do the default values come?
```

Now the part that really bothers me. On another board a have a eMMC uEnv.txt file that looks like this.

```
optargs=quiet drm.debug=7 capemgr.enable_partno=BB-UART2,BB-UART1
```

The board boots fine without uSD.

```
Question 3.   
    How is that even posible?
```

Comment: *"Question 2. Where do the default values come?"* -- The default environment variables are compiled into U-Boot.  They are typically defined in the board's configuration file.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to the question should be in your board configuration file. Specifically the definition of 'CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS'- "Define this to contain any number of null terminated strings (variable = value pairs) that will be part of the default environment compiled into the boot image." (from u-boot README file)